# Airflow: BigQueryOperator vs BigQuery Quotas and Limits

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

Is there any pratical way to control quotas and limits on Airflow?.

I'm specially interested on controlling BigQuery concurrency.

There are different levels of [quotas on BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) . So according to the Operator inputs, there should be a way to check if conditions are met, otherwise waiting for it to fulfill.

It seems to be a composition of Sensor-Operators, querying against a database like redis for example:

```
QuotaSensor(Project, Dataset, Table, Query) >> QuotaAddOperator(Project, Dataset, Table, Query)
QuotaAddOperator(Project, Dataset, Table, Query) >> BigQueryOperator(Project, Dataset, Table, Query)
BigQueryOperator(Project, Dataset, Table, Query) >> QuotaSubOperator(Project, Dataset, Table, Query)
```

The Sensor must check conditions like:

```
- Global running queries <= 300
- Project running queries <= 100
- .. etc
```

Is there any lib that already does that for me? A plugin perhaps?
Or any other easier solution?

Otherwise, following the Sensor-Operators approach.
How can I encapsulate all of it under a single operator? To avoid repetition of code, 
a single operator: QuotaBigQueryOperator

Comment: Hi @Roghen. In order to properly understand what you want to do, could you please explain a potential use case? What I mean is, when a quota limit is about to be reached what do you want to do? Stop Airflow from sending BQ jobs for a while? Another question for confirmation: you want to act upon the quota usage from your code itself, isn't it? If not [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring) could be useful for [creating alerts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring#create-alert) when a given quota exceeds any limit you define.

Comment: Hi @Javier. Exactly. Currently I have a BQ Sql Orchestrator (running on Jenkins) that allows a maximum of 40 running jobs per project.. I have multiple products (around ~200), each one with a specific GCP Project. Which is awesome to keep the billing separated... Anyway, there's use cases of data processing that triggers queues of hundreds of queries per a project. And I need workers/operators waiting until a slot is available... I don't need exaclty alerts, I just need the dag not to stop or break for ratelimit reasons... So I'm trying to achieve on Airflow the same behavior our Jenkins has.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is only possible to get the [Compute Engine quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#checking_your_quota) programmatically. However, there is an opened [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80238692) to get/set other project quotas via API. You can post there about the specific case you would like to have implemented and [follow it](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) to track it and ask for updates.

Meanwhile, as workaround you can try to use the [PythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/python.html). With it you can define your own custom code and you would be able to implement retries for the queries that you send that get a [quotaExceeded error](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages#quotaExceeded) (or the specific error you are getting). In this way you wouldn't have to explicitly check for the quota levels. You just run the queries and retry until they get executed. This is a simplified code for the strategy I am thinking about:

```
for query in QUERIES_TO_RUN:
    while True:
        try:
            run(query)
        except quotaExceededException:
            continue  # Jumps to the next cycle of the nearest enclosing loop.
        break
```